# Change the country where Google account is managed

Tags: google-account, account-management

Many years ago, I had signed up for a Google Account when I lived in the UK. I have since moved to Germany, and changed my address, country for Google Play and contact telephone number all to Germany (and currently there is no payment information on file, but previously it was a German credit card linked to a German address)

However, it seems that Google still considers me to be a UK customer, as I received an email informing me that the data centre responsible for my account will be moved to the United States. The pertinent excerpts from Google's email are:

> The changes will take effect on March 31, 2020, and they won’t impact the way you use Google services. And, because the United Kingdom (UK) is leaving the European Union (EU), Google LLC will now be the service provider and the data controller responsible for your information and for complying with applicable privacy laws for UK consumer users.

and

> Because the UK is leaving the EU, we’ve updated our Terms so that a United States based company, Google LLC, is now your service provider instead of Google Ireland Limited. Google LLC will also become the data controller responsible for your information and complying with applicable privacy laws.

However, as a customer residing in Germany, I believe my data should continue to be hosted in Ireland and be governed by European laws. I do not want processing of my data to be subject to US or UK laws.
Short of deleting my account, is there any option to change the 'true' country account. Account deletion is highly undesirable, as (1) it would means dropping my current GoogleID, which I like for its simplicity, (2) require transferring over a large number of documents in Google Drive, several of them under active collaborative editing, and some other reasons.

I spent some time trawling through the Google Support pages, but all country changes anyone ever seems to talk about there is for Google Play, which I have already changed many years ago to the correct country.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 12 times. I’m voting to close this question because it relates to the terms of service. [law.se] might be better suited to handle questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

If not already done so, have you tried changing your home location on Google Maps? A lot of Google services use this setting for determining a user's current physical location.

Go to Google Maps, click on the hamburger and select Your Places, then select Labeled.
This then has an option to set a Home and Work location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's a good idea but did not fix my problem. Actually, I have since figured out that when I navigate to Terms and Conditions from inside my account then I am shown the T&Cs for Germany, which flat out contradict the email I have been sent (and yes, I have checked that there is really only one account). So I have come across an inconsistency, essentially a bug. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to contact Google to sort this out.

Comment: If it's a bug, which it would appear to be (as you have mentioned) you may want to bring it up on Google's own Google Accounts Help Community. It may help get some eyes on the issue and lead to it getting fixed. You can find the community here https://support.google.com/accounts/threads?hl=en

Comment: After not receiving an answer here for a day, and few views, I have already tried that, but so far no reaction. Still maybe it will be picked up. Anyway, thanks for being helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of customer service / policies, not a topic about using a web app, as the message you received refers to the Terms of Service.

---

Source: https://policies.google.com/faq?hl=en-US

> ## Why is my account associated with a country?
>
> Your account is associated with a country (or territory) in the Terms of Service so that we can determine two things:
>
> 1. The Google affiliate that provides the services, that processes your information, and that is responsible for complying with applicable privacy laws. Generally, Google offers its consumer services through either of two companies:
>
>    - Google Ireland Limited, if you’re located in the European Economic Area (EU countries plus Iceland, Liechtenstein, and Norway) or Switzerland
>    - Google LLC, based in the United States, for the rest of the world
> 2. The version of the terms that govern our relationship, which can vary depending on local laws
>
> Keep in mind that Google services are essentially the same regardless of the affiliate that provides the services or your country association.

Comment: I am sorry I disagree with this justification at least. The question was how do I change the country, which is a practical question how to achieve this, and not questioning the terms-of-service per se. Information on these was provided for background and motivation. I don't mind if the question is closed as nobody knew the answer anyway but still object to the stated reason.